# How to find the range of $T : M_n(\Bbb{R}) \to M_n(\Bbb{R})$ given by $T(A) = A + A^t$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

How to find the range of the linear transformation given by
$$T(A)=A+A^t$$
with $A$ being an $n\times n$ matrix?

I have absolutely nothing except that $(A+A^t)^t=A+A^t$ which would make $A+A^t$ symmetric but how does that affect the range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a square matrix $A\in\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$ it's clear that $T(A)$ is a symmetric matrix so
$$\operatorname{im} T\subset \mathcal S_n(\Bbb R)$$
and if $B\in \mathcal S_n(\Bbb R)$ then $T\left(\frac12 B\right)=B$ hence
$$\mathcal S_n(\Bbb R)\subset \operatorname{im} T$$
so we conclude that
$$\mathcal S_n(\Bbb R)=\operatorname{im} T$$

Comment: Does $S_n(R)$ refer to symmetric matrices? and Does $imT$ refer to T(A)?

Comment: Yes $\mathcal S_n(\Bbb R)$ is set (vector space) of symmetric matrices and $\rm im$ is the notation of the image and has the same meaning as the range.